# Solve: $f''(x) = f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, inverse-function, golden-ratio

I found this differential equation $$ f''(x) = f^{-1}(x) $$ which is interesting to me.

I wonder if there is a calculus oriented way to solve this differential equation. Is there some method to to solve differential equations containing inverse of a function ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This asks for second derivative - the linked question asks for first. Too many questions are being closed unjustifiably.

Comment: @martycohen initially asked that, but then I was looking for the solution of this secord order one.

Comment: Then resubmit it, making sure to explicitly say that it is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Yeah, now it is not a duplicate anymore. The question has been reopened

Comment: If we start by assuming a solution of the form $f(x)=\alpha x^\beta$ we get a solution on $\mathbb{R}^+$ with $\beta=1\pm\sqrt{2}$ and $\alpha=(\beta^2-\beta)^{-\beta/(1+\beta)}$

Comment: I would to have a more general insight to it.